# Hide "Add new" for just one module

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

I'll like to know if it's possible to hide the "Add new" link in some modules, for example I have this:

```
Module 1 ----- Add  ------ List
Module 2 ----- Add  ------ List
Module 3 ----- Add  ------ List
Module 4 ----- Add  ------ List
```

But I want this:

```
Module 1 -----      ------ List
Module 2 ----- Add  ------ List
Module 3 ----- Add  ------ List
Module 4 -----      ------ List
```

How I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, May be helpful.

```
    $formMapper
            ->add('Module1', null,array())
            ->add('Module2', 'sonata_type_model',array())
            ->add('Module3', 'sonata_type_model',array())
            ->add('Module4', null,array())
```

In **add** method set **null** second arguments to hide "add new" button